# android genymotion iptables

Tags: android, iptables, genymotion

I am using Genymotion emulator for Testing My proxy.So I need use iptables to redirect all tcp data to my proxy Port.
when I use

```
iptables -t nat -N REDSOCKS
```

it prints 'can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)'

But when I use

```
iptables -L
```

it prints the default table 'filter' complete chains.

'nat' and 'filter' are default tables in netfilter, Why nat table does not exist？

Answer (score 0):

**Users of retail Android devices cannot access iptables binary. Even Android OS itself cannot access that binary.**
[Source.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/81753/dnat-iptables-rule-on-rooted-android-phone)

[A few general things about routing with iptables.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126595/iptables-forward-all-traffic-to-interface)

Dont forget to enable routing .

1. sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

   or
2. echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

and

3. iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $device -p tcp --dport $srcPortNumber
   -j REDIRECT --to-port $dstPortNumber